# How to remove overridden styles from css?

Tags: html, css

We have a large CSS file with many styles that contains overriden styles like this:

```
.block {
    width: 100px;
}
...
.block {
    width: 200px;
}
```

We want to automatically remove unused styles and get as result only 1 style property value for the class like this:

```
.block {
    width: 200px;
}
```

https://purifycss.online/  - This does not solve our problem.

[purifycss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYfIE.jpg)

How can I do it having only html and CSS files?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio Code you can install the plugin named DupChecker

Comment: for .block, you put ".block: 200px !important". This has to be latest (in code, imported, link rel file).

Comment: @pierfarrugia use !important is not a good choice, and don't solve the problem

Comment: but you should consider that CSS is called cascading for a reason. The point is that it could be immensely difficult or virtually impossible to reduce your css rules because some rules are supposed to collide by design on the same element when all the conditions are met. On the other end, if by duplicates you mean only rules having the same exact selector that's another story

Comment: Yes, only rules having the same exact selector

Comment: @Sfilli_81, important is awful and not working in all cases. But it's sometimes (often) a saver. As saying Diego D, CSS is cascading. If you control all your CSS, better to rewrite correctly your CSS to avoid duplicates. Sometimes you don't have access, can't modify, some files. In this case important can help